# Python using pandas_datareader to read from FRED gives error no timezone found

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am trying to use pandas_datareader to read from FRED.
Code is below but I get this error

- GDP: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted

The code is taken from the doco
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-fred

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27)
gdp = web.DataReader('GDP', 'fred', start, end,ignore_tz=True)
```

I tried googling the error,
I tried hard coding dates with time zones
I also tired using ignore_tz argument set to True

Comment: By FRED, you mean the St. Louis FED data. Check your ignore_tz parameter. I'll feed back once I get access to system

Comment: Hello thats right By FRED, I mean the St. Louis FED data, I tried the ignore_tz parameter I set it to TRUE but no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB: In Colab, I get an error with the keyword `ignore_tz`
From `Remote Data Access` [pandas_datareader documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#fred), it is not required.

You can simply format your datetime to your preferred timezone using the datetime's timezone library.

```py
%%time

## import libraries
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

## timerange  ##Edit per @Jim comment
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27)

## Read St. Louis FED data
## Documentation at: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#fred
## Read 'GDP' data from FRED within the timerange
gdp = web.DataReader('GDP', 'fred', start, end)

## display retrieved dataframe from source
gdp
```

I got output as below (showing the first 5).

```py
CPU times: user 24 ms, sys: 903 µs, total: 24.9 ms
Wall time: 283 ms
Date         GDP    
2010-01-01  14764.611
2010-04-01  14980.193
2010-07-01  15141.605
2010-10-01  15309.471
2011-01-01  15351.444
```

PS: I'll give this another shot on my system to handle the `ignore_tz` with better option. However, `ignore_tz = True` would not be the option.

Comment: Thank you, if I cut and paste your code I get "UsageError: Line magic function `%%` not found." for the kline %% timerange

Comment: Hint: in `start` and `end`, leverage `datetime` `timezone`, `astimezone()`

Comment: @Jim error fixed `## timerange`

Comment: dug up an old windows laptop and my original code runs with out an issue so there is something about running from my Macbook, both are running same code and same version of pycharm and same internet connection

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Quick one. By saying working fine on the old Win laptop, is that with or without the `timezone`

Comment: Also, what are the libraries versions running on the 'old' Win laptop; including python.

Comment: python 3.8 on both, will check libraries working on old laptop without the time zone

Comment: If you don't need the `timezone`, you probably shouldn't bother about the `timezone`. The #edited code that I posted works fine by me. When I get time, I'll just convert St Louis time to my SA time. That doesn't seem critical, though.    Curious, have you tried retrieving FRED directly using `api` call. Possibly, FRED from panda_datareader isn't `timezone` aware.  Unfortunately, I can't do much right away without direct access to my system.

Comment: Ive just tried running your code and i get "No timezone found, symbol may be delisted". Ive tried it with a couple other codes and no luck. Have they changed something in their API?